# PHP beginner: Best practice for inserting into multiple tables with foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning basic PHP MySQL right now.

As of now I have 2 tables; a `zoo` table (parent table) and a `species` table (child table).

The `zoo` table contains `ID (PK)` and `animal_name`. The `species` table contains an `ID (PK)` and `animal_id (FK; zoo.ID)` and `species_name`.

My question here is what is the best practice to insert into a multiple table when I create a row in the `zoo` table.

Currently, the idea that comes to my mind is to have 2 SQL statement and the process is like this:-

1. Insert animal_name to zoo
2. Get last ID in zoo table.
3. Close cursor
4. Insert animal_id (last insert ID of
   zoo) and species_name to species
   table
5. Close cursor

Is this the best practice? Is there anyway I can improve this process with scalability in mind? (i.e. when I add more tables with foreign key referencing to `zoo` table in the near future?

I have searched around here and some comrades suggested triggers but however it is not supported in MyISAM storage engine. I'm using MyISAM engine with PHP PDO MySQL object.

Comment: `Get last ID in zoo table.` --- use `PDO::lastInsertId()` instead. Btw, what are you using cursors for?

Comment: Cursors don't scale. Forget they even exist, except in the rare ninja cases. When working with RDBMSs, think set-based.

Answer (score 1):

With PDO, you can get the ID of the row you just inserted without another query - just do
`$newRowID = $conn->lastInsertId();`

where $conn is your database connection.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MySQL built-in facilities for finding the last generated identity.

So for your Item 2, use this SQL statement:

```
`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`
```

This gets the last auto incremented ID on your connection. Load that value into a variable, and use that in your Item 4 `INSERT` statement.

[How to Get the Unique ID for the Last Inserted Row with MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/getting-unique-id.html)

Comment: Since he is using `php pdo` it is more appropriate to use `PDO::lastInsertId()`

Comment: Thanks zerkms. I approached it with a SQL mindframe, but your suggestion works well. Perhaps this could all be done in 1 SQL statement, wrapped in a transaction, even.